# Xamarin.Forms + ReactiveUI + Xamvvm View not updating on iOS only

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, reactiveui

We're building a cross platform app using Xamarin.Forms with ReactiveUI.
The app structure is based on the following example:

https://github.com/GiusepeCasagrande/reactive-dev-days-lab

The Android version works as expected, however, on the iOS simulator, when you run the command "SyncSpeakers", the command executes successfully, the view flickers but the list is not populated.

Can anyone understand why this might be happening? 
Should I abandon using xammvvm for the routing and switch to something else?

[image: iOS list]

[image: Android version working]

The ViewModel code for speakers as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reactive;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using DevDaysSpeakers.Model;
using DevDaysSpeakers.Services;
using ReactiveUI;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamvvm;

namespace DevDaysSpeakers.ViewModel
{
    public class SpeakersViewModel: BasePageModelRxUI
    {
        public ReactiveList<Speaker> Speakers { get; } = new ReactiveList<Speaker>();

        Speaker speaker;
        public Speaker Speaker
        {
            get { return speaker; }
            set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref speaker, value); }
        }

        public ReactiveCommand<Unit, IEnumerable<Speaker>> GetSpeakers { get; }

        public ReactiveCommand GoToDetails { get; }

        readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<bool> busy;
        public bool IsBusy => busy.Value;

        public SpeakersViewModel()
            : this(null)
        {

        }

        public SpeakersViewModel(AzureService azureService = null)
        {
            var service = azureService ?? DependencyService.Get<AzureService>();

            GetSpeakers = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(_ => service.GetSpeakers());

            GetSpeakers
                .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
                .SubscribeOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
                .Subscribe(speakers =>
                {
                    Speakers.Clear();
                    Speakers.AddRange(speakers);
                });

            GetSpeakers.IsExecuting
                .ToProperty(this, vm => vm.IsBusy, out busy);

            GetSpeakers.ThrownExceptions
                .Subscribe(error => Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error!", error.Message, "OK"));

            // go to details page when Speaker is set
            this.WhenAnyValue(vm => vm.Speaker)
                .Where(speaker => speaker != null)
                .Subscribe(speaker => this.PushPageFromCacheAsync<DetailsViewModel>(vm => vm.Speaker = speaker));

            this.ThrownExceptions
                .Subscribe(ex =>
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The XAML for the view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<reactive:ReactiveContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    xmlns:reactive="clr-namespace:ReactiveUI.XamForms;assembly=ReactiveUI.XamForms" 
    xmlns:xamvvm="clr-namespace:Xamvvm;assembly=Xamvvm.Forms.RxUI" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DevDaysSpeakers.ViewModel;assembly=DevDaysSpeakers" 
    x:Class="DevDaysSpeakers.View.SpeakersPage" 
    x:TypeArguments="local:SpeakersViewModel" 
    Title="Speakers" 
    x:Name="ThePage">
    <reactive:ReactiveContentPage.Padding>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness" iOS="0, 20, 0, 0" />
    </reactive:ReactiveContentPage.Padding>
    <reactive:ReactiveContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Spacing="0">
            <Button x:Name="SyncSpeakers" Text="Sync Speakers" />
            <ActivityIndicator x:Name="IsBusy" />
            <ListView x:Name="ListViewSpeakers">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ImageCell Text="{Binding Name}" Detail="{Binding Title}" ImageSource="{Binding Avatar}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </reactive:ReactiveContentPage.Content>
</reactive:ReactiveContentPage>
```

Code behind of the view

```
using System.Reactive.Disposables;
using DevDaysSpeakers.ViewModel;
using ReactiveUI;
using Xamvvm;

namespace DevDaysSpeakers.View
{
    public partial class SpeakersPage 
        : IBasePageRxUI<SpeakersViewModel>
    {
        public SpeakersPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.WhenActivated(disposables =>
            {
                this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, x => x.Speakers, x => x.ListViewSpeakers.ItemsSource).DisposeWith(disposables);
                this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, x => x.GetSpeakers, x => x.SyncSpeakers.Command).DisposeWith(disposables);
                this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, x => x.IsBusy, x => x.IsBusy.IsVisible).DisposeWith(disposables);
                this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, x => x.IsBusy, x => x.IsBusy.IsEnabled).DisposeWith(disposables);
                this.Bind(ViewModel, x => x.Speaker, x => x.ListViewSpeakers.SelectedItem).DisposeWith(disposables);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Project.json for iOS

```
{
  "supports": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.SQLiteStore": "3.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Bcl.Build": "1.0.21",
    "reactiveui-events-xamforms": "7.1.0",
    "reactiveui-xamforms": "7.1.0",
    "SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_e_sqlite3": "1.1.2",
    "Xam.Plugins.TextToSpeech": "2.0.0",
    "Xamarin.Forms": "2.3.3.180",
    "Xamvvm.Forms.RxUI": "1.0.2"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    ".NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile7": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you just try updating to RxUI 7.2 Curious if it's the same effect I have seen before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Xamarin.Forms bug. You can see the discussion over here https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/issues/806

And here is the bug itself: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=31415

In the first link you can find a few workarounds, one really easy is just change the ReactiveList for a ObservableCollection.